# syntax error in insert into statement with ms access database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data into ms access database , but i'm keep getting syntax error in insert into statement.

Code:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection mycon;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sidd\Desktop\Database1.mdb");

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string insertcmd = "insert into comp (pro_ps,pro_type,pro_nam,pro_det) values( '"+TextBox1.Text +"','"+TextBox1.Text  +"','"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox1.Text+"')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertcmd, mycon);
        mycon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TextBox2.Text = "DONE";
    }

}
```

database :
[image]

Comment: Concatenated SQL String, what if user writes in TextBox1.Text sth like `' DROP TABLE ...; --`?

Comment: What's the error mesage?  What are the values in the text boxes?  Also consider using parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: `comp` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#C).  If you can't rename that table, bracket the name in your SQL statement like this ... `insert into [comp]`

Comment: Why are you inserting `TextBox1.Text` into all your columns? Is this just example of your problem or just a quick debug test of your code? Also, you should use parameters to help cut down on your possible security issues.

Comment: it makes me sick when I see developers use poor or null notations/prefixes :( :(